# Pop Up HTML Image when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so I have a few pictures on a website that im creating (Please not im learning as I go along). I would like users to be able to click the image and view a full a pop up of the image, so like the original size of the actual image, I have added the code for the pictures below.

```
<section id="main">
          <div class="inner">
            <section>

<div class="box alt">
      <div class="row 50% uniform">

                              <div class="4u"><span class="image fit"><img 
src="images/marble/1.jpg" width="321" height="230" alt="" /><h3>Marble</h3>
</span></div>

                                <div class="4u"><span class="image fit"><img 
src="images/marble/2.jpg" width="321" height="230" alt="" /><h3>Marble</h3>
</span></div>
                                <div class="4u"><span class="image fit"><img 
src="images/marble/3.jpg" width="321" height="230" alt="" /><h3>Marble</h3>
</span></div>

    </div>
              </div>
</section>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Hover:

```
.image.fit >img:hover {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: You will need to have two versions of each image (the small thumbnail and the full-size image). But, we're not a code writing service. You have to give it a shot and come back with any specific programming problems you are having.

Comment: You could just wrap an `<a>` around the smaller  `<img />`, linking directly to the image, or better yet to a page that centers the image, as some Browsers don't do that automatically.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have added the code I used to make a hover, is it possible to make that hover over all other images? At the moment its hovering under all the other images

Comment: Maybe this will help you open multiple images: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` elements should be completely removed and its classes placed on the image elements themselves.

Also, you have a nested `section` element that isn't doing anything for you.

Lastly, do not use HTML heading elements (`<h1>`...`<h6>`) because of the way they style the text. Formatting is the job of CSS. Instead of headings, it is more appropriate to surround each image and its accompanying text with `figure` and `figcaption` elements.

```css
img { 
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid black; /* This is only added for testing purposes*/
}

.thumbnail:hover {
   width: 500px;
   height:auto;
   position:relative;
   /* push image to the right by 1/2 the screen width and 1/2 the image width */
   margin-left:calc(50% - 250px);
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box alt">
      <div class="row 50% uniform">
         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg" alt="" class="thumbnail">
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>

         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <img src="http://www.critterbabies.com/wp-content/gallery/kittens/cats-animals-kittens-background-us.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail">
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>
         
         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/08482-Fluffy-ginger-female-kitten.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail">
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>
         
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: reminds you of friendster days

Answer (score 1):

I've taken [Scott Marcus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45045997/4665) and adapted to click, which was your original request.

The main diffence is the addition of `a` tags targeting elements on the page and using `:target` in the css.

```css
img { 
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid black; /* This is only added for testing purposes*/
}

.thumbnail:target {
   width: 500px;
   height:auto;
   position:relative;
   /* push image to the right by 1/2 the screen width and 1/2 the image width */
   margin-left:calc(50% - 250px);
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box alt">
      <div class="row 50% uniform">
         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <a href="#image1">
             <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg" alt="" class="thumbnail" id="image1">
             </a>
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>

         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <a href="#image2">
             <img src="http://www.critterbabies.com/wp-content/gallery/kittens/cats-animals-kittens-background-us.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail" id="image2">
             </a>
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>
         
         <div class="4u">
           <figure>
             <a href="#image3">
             <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/08482-Fluffy-ginger-female-kitten.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail" id="image3">
             </a>
             <figcaption>Marble</figcaption>
           </figure>
         </div>
         
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```